# Receiving from a .fold "emit was called after an event handler completed normally."

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-bloc, dartz

Since I found the solution hidden of my problem in the comments, I am putting it here in a more prominent place:

Problem: I received the above error after awaiting some function within a Dart `.fold` method.

```dart
_failureOrProperty.fold(
          (failure) async => emit(state.copyWith(
              status: () => DataTransStatus.failure,
          (data) async {
            final List<int>? taskTypeCnts = await getTasksCount(_calledId!);
//            final List<int>? taskTypeCnts=[1,1];
            emit(state.copyWith(
                status: () => DataTransStatus.success,
                noOfMandatory: () => taskTypeCnts?[0],
                noOfOptional: () => taskTypeCnts?[1]
            ));
          }
```

Using the line in the comment, everything works fine, awaiting `getTasksCount()` does not.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is amending the first line with `await`

```dart
await _failureOrProperty.fold(. // PLACING await IN FRONT OF THE .fold
          (failure) async => emit(state.copyWith(
              status: () => DataTransStatus.failure,
          (data) async {
            final List<int>? taskTypeCnts = await getTasksCount(_calledId!);
//            final List<int>? taskTypeCnts=[1,1];
            emit(state.copyWith(
                status: () => DataTransStatus.success,
                noOfMandatory: () => taskTypeCnts?[0],
                noOfOptional: () => taskTypeCnts?[1]
            ));
          }
```

Comment: This solved my problem, so thank you!
Then I understood why this is obvious: the fold() must be awaited since at least one of the two cases is async and this makes the fold() function async too.